# How would I go about overclocking my Intel Pentium N3700?

Tags: cpu, overclocking

I've searched all over the 'net for this one, and I couldn't really find anything that would allow me to overclock my CPU.

My CPU model is an [Intel Pentium N3700](http://ark.intel.com/products/87261/Intel-Pentium-Processor-N3700-2M-Cache-up-to-2_40-GHz) quad-core operating at 1.6 GHz base and 2.4 GHz Turbo. I'm trying to turn a [Lenovo IdeaCentre 300s](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/desktops/ideacentre/300-series/300s-11/) into a gaming PC, and the CPU currently bottlenecks the system. I have an overclocked [Low-Profile Gigabyte GeForce GTX 750 Ti](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00MW8NXAW) as a GPU.

The BIOS has nothing in there that will allow me to OC the CPU.

What else can I try to overclock the CPU with? Is there something in Windows that will allow me to do that?

Comment: If it is not in the bios, you cannot, overclocking is done at the bios level of hardware abstraction.

Comment: Can I change the BIOS at all, then?

Comment: You can update to a new version but where you are going with your question answer is going to be no

Comment: Replace the motherboard and CPU, stock OEM PCs are not capable of overclocked 99.99% of the time... Even if you could overclock it, the gains with that CPU would be minimal. To be honest, for a minimal investment you could make leaps and bounds gains by using a new budget motherboard and CPU.